# How to get a dictionary source?

Tags: android, iphone, windows

I want to make a dictionary, to start with i will go for a english dictionary. What is the source for this ? From where can i get the dictionary content ? how are dictionary apps usually made ?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dictionary.com

Most apps create a database or some server that feeds information.

Comment: yea, i want to go ahead wherein i will create a database for the info, but i wanted to know from where i could fetch the data....is there any feed that already someone provides ?

Comment: No, most apps that have this functionality has its on database with definitions. Most likely on a server. You should google around a bit. Some one may have something out there. But i wouldnt be sure of how acurrate it would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt) text file, provided by Oracle

Comment: Under the [Code sample license (BSD)](http://developers.sun.com/license/berkeley_license.html), of course.

Comment: Interesting, Is there any other text file which provides the meaning for all the words in this file ? I want to make a dictionary app which can fetch the values from the database rather than going for a webservice.

Comment: Google is the answer to all questions ever created :D

Answer (score 0):

Since it is tagged with iPhone, you can use the built-in dictionary of the iPhone by playing with `UITextChecker` 
I used it to a word game app I was developing.

[see reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the infor. I tagged with iPhone as i wanted ideas from mobile app developers :)